# Count continuous cell vallues and reset the count if the cell value changes

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In Excel or Google Sheets, I want to implement something like a habit tracker.

Ex: Let X wants to do exercise for a continuous 30 days.

He will enter whether he did the exercise on a particular day or not by entering Yes for doing and no for not doing exercise.

All I want to count is the number of continuous "Yes".

If he enters "No" in-between for a single day then count will start from 0 for the any "Yes" he enters next.

I need to display the count of continuous dates at the top row.
For example, if he did the exercise for 10 days, I want to display this on the top row, so that end-user can see the count at a glance whenever he needs.

Hope I am clear.

Note: The end-user won't enter the formula in each cell to calculate the count.
I want to enter the formula and that too only for once. It should be independent of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes", 
 MMULT(N(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))>=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)))), 
 N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes"))-HLOOKUP(0, 
 MMULT(N(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))>
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)))), 
 N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes")), MATCH(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 IF(N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)<>B1:B), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), ), 1, 1),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 IF(N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)<>B1:B), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), ), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset "&COUNTIF(B2:B, "yes")-1, 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes", 
 MMULT(N(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))>=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)))), 
 N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes"))-HLOOKUP(0, 
 MMULT(N(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))>
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)))), 
 N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)="Yes")), MATCH(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 IF(N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)<>B1:B), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), ), 1, 1),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 IF(N(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)<>B1:B), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), 0), 
 "offset "&COUNTIF(B2:B, "<>")-1, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Because of the last no, the count should become 0

Comment: Query completed with an empty output error I am getting if I move the starting row to 3

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a formula that compares current value with 'yes' , if it is `TRUE` then make increment, if not set 0.

Below is an example of the formula in `C3` cell assuming that you have yes/no in column `B`:

```
=IF(B3="yes", C2+1, 0)
```

If you need only the last value then enter the following formula in `D1` for example:

```
=INDEX(B:C,COUNTA(B:B),2)
```

[image]

Comment: The end-user won't enter the formula in each cell to calculate the count. I want to enter the formula and that too only for once. It should be independent of rows.

Comment: You enter the formula only once and spread it across all rows. This is 1 time operation, just copy cell with the function, select a row and use `Paste Special` -> `Formula`. Then you could hide this column if it is not needed. Formula is rather easy to understand so I believe this solution is very straightforward and maintainable

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in google sheets, inspired through [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104064/count-number-of-consecutive-entries-with-arrayformula-in-google-sheets) post:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B32="Yes",MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B32)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B32))),N(B2:B32="Yes"))-HLOOKUP(0,MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B32)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B32))),N(B2:B32="Yes")),MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B32),IF(N(B2:B32<>B1:B31),ROW(B2:B32),),1,TRUE),VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B32),IF(N(B2:B32<>B1:B31),ROW(B2:B32),),1,TRUE),0),FALSE),))
```

Only one formula to be entered.

And to make it row independent (no matter the amount of days):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))="Yes",MMULT(N(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A)))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))))),N(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))="Yes"))-HLOOKUP(0,MMULT(N(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A)))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))))),N(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))="Yes")),MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))),IF(N(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))<>B1:index(B:B,counta(A:A)-1)),ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))),),1,TRUE),VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))),IF(N(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))<>B1:index(B:B,counta(A:A)-1)),ROW(B2:index(B:B,counta(A:A))),),1,TRUE),0),FALSE),))
```

Or, if you don't care about the speed of the spreadsheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="Yes",MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))),N(B2:B="Yes"))-HLOOKUP(0,MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))),N(B2:B="Yes")),MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B),IF(N(B2:B32<>B1:B),ROW(B2:B),),1,TRUE),VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B),IF(N(B2:B<>B1:B),ROW(B2:B),),1,TRUE),0),FALSE),))
```

---

If you are interested in the last value of the last sequence of "Yes" you can use this formula to retrieve that value:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(9.99E+307,C:C))
```

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, how can I get the last count and show it on the top row?

Comment: You mean the value 4?

Comment: Yes, in our case it 4. It can be anything else in realtime.

Comment: You can build some formula to retrieve the last value other than ""

Comment: Which formula I should use for it?